# node.js 100% CPU

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with my node.js application. I'm using websocket to transfer data to mysql and all works good and fast till the time when node will raise to consume 100% cpu, such 100% take a long time, about 1 hour. And during this all communications between server and websockets are much slow down. Somebody know where is reason and how to resolve it?

Here are screens from server:

top command:
[image: top command]

Profiler:
[image: Profiler]

Comment: I second that question, I have the same issue with node. I'm running at 100% CPU and it's taking 30-40 min to do something simple.

Comment: 100% cpu use might have various reasons. Callbacks that are not resolved,connections that are not closed properly, ... . It is nearly impossible to tell you the reason without debugging your code.

Comment: According to the profiler screenshot, garbage collector eats most of the CPU. Check your code, you may have memory leaks that have to be handled by GC.

Comment: have you already tried to destroy the unused mysql connection?

Comment: How are you setting up your connections?? As a lot more people are saying you have a memory leak if you have multiple connections to the database do you close them? As I had a similar problem with redis and this was the reason

Comment: Hi dennington , I have the same issue with node and redis. I am using a query and inside I loop forEach result and store into a redis client. I am only using connection.end() when the loop is over. But it is not enough and I end up with a fatal error. Do I have to close connection with redis as well ?